# How to test content of a Django email?

Tags: python, django, email

I'm new to Django and am trying to use `unittest` to check if there's some text in an outbound email:

```
class test_send_daily_email(TestCase):
    def test_success(self):
        self.assertIn(mail.outbox[0].body, "My email's contents")
```

However, I'm having an issue with `mail.outbox[0].body`. It will output `\nMy email&#39s contents\n` and won't match the test text.

I've attempted a few different fixes with no luck:

- `str(mail.outbox[0].body).rstrip()` - returns an idential string
- `str(mail.outbox[0].body).decode('utf-8')` - no attribute decode

Apologies, I know this must be a trivial task. In Rails I would use something like Nokogiri to parse the text. What's the right way to parse this in Django? I wasn't able to find instructions on this in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#email-services).

Comment: Can you please post code sending email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the actual content of your mail (plain or html) but the easy way is to also encode the string you are testing against.

```
# if you are testing HTML content
self.assertTextInHTML("My email's contents", mail.outbox[0].body)

# the string may need escaping the same way django escapes
from django.utils.html import escape
self.assertIn(escape("My email's contents"), mail.outbox[0].body)
```